# Seal on vase identification help (Characters identified: 工藝)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

[image: vase image]

This is the seal on the vase I’m trying to identify. The picture is of a bird and flowers. Thank you!

Comment: That red seal should be two words. If you can take pictures of all the words on this bottle, I may be able to find out what it is, where it is made, and what purpose it is used for.

Answer (score 0):

from right to left: (the far right is hard to identify because of the angle)
花**似锦 鸟弄舌如簧
Describing the beautiful blossoms and melodious birdsong.